# Android Studio Assets Folder Missing

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to add an assets folder in Android Studio but it is not an option to me.  When I go into the android view and try to create a new folder I am only presented with these options.
[image]
An alternative answer I found was to go to the packages view; however, I could not see my project directory from there.  Does anyone know a way to add it as an option?  Thanks!

Comment: You can create `src/main/assets/` directory and android studio will load it

Comment: your code is not recognized as runnable, try to invalidate caches and restart from the file menu

Comment: @LenaBru I invalidated caches and restarted as you suggested and the same issue is present.  Would you be able to explain more why I cannot create an assets folder for code not recognized as runnable?  I am new to android studio and it seems like I should still be able to create a directory even if I cannot run code.

Answer (score 7):

Right-click on app folder go to **New> Folder>Assets Folder**.
Android Studio will open a dialog box.  Keep all the settings default. Under the target source set, option **main** should be selected. and click finish.

Comment: I shared a picture in my question where this is not present as an option to me.  I am able to create a new directory and name it assets, but I am unsure (and doubtful) that this is the same thing.

Comment: I hope that creating it in that way will work
Did you try to run the project or something before?

Comment: What I meant to say is I would like to have the other options available as I am unsure why they are not listed for me.

Comment: @mradey right click on "app" folder you will get the folders option

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue.  My gradle file was not updated and I needed to sync dependencies.  Once doing that I was presented with the option to create an assets folder.